# How to infer schema of JSON files?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the following String in Java

```
{
    "header": {
        "gtfs_realtime_version": "1.0",
        "incrementality": 0,
        "timestamp": 1528460625,
        "user-data": "metra"
    },
    "entity": [{
            "id": "8424",
            "vehicle": {
                "trip": {
                    "trip_id": "UP-N_UN314_V1_D",
                    "route_id": "UP-N",
                    "start_time": "06:17:00",
                    "start_date": "20180608",
                    "schedule_relationship": 0
                },
                "vehicle": {
                    "id": "8424",
                    "label": "314"
                },
                "position": {
                    "latitude": 42.10085,
                    "longitude": -87.72896
                },
                "current_status": 2,
                "timestamp": 1528460601
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

that represent a JSON document. I want to infer a schema in a **Spark** Dataframe for a **streaming application**.

How can I split the fields of the String similarly to a CSV document (where I can call `.split("")`)?

Comment: Do you have a case class that represents this JSON? BTW., Infering in Structured Streaming is not possible, only in batch

Comment: I have not the class, but the structure of the fields is standard... I have seen in the Spark Programming Guide it is possible to infer the schema with these commands:
     `Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
         .readStream()
         .format("kafka")
         .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KafkaFeeds.kafkaBrokerEndpoint)
         .option("subscribe", "kafkaToSparkTopic")
         .load();`

Comment: What, exactly, do you want as output after “splitting” the sample json string?

Comment: I would like to extract only some fields of the JSON document, for example the "latitude" value of the position field. So I want to have a easy-to-split format (as CSV .split(""))

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the official documentation [Schema inference and partition of streaming DataFrames/Datasets](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#schema-inference-and-partition-of-streaming-dataframesdatasets):

> By default, Structured Streaming from file based sources requires you to specify the schema, rather than rely on Spark to infer it automatically. This restriction ensures a consistent schema will be used for the streaming query, even in the case of failures. For ad-hoc use cases, you can reenable schema inference by setting `spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference` to true.

You can then use `spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference` configuration property to enable schema inference. I'm not sure if that's going to work for JSON files.

What I usually do is to load a single file (in a batch query and before starting a streaming query) to infer the schema. That should work in your case. Just do the following.

```
// I'm leaving converting Scala to Java as a home exercise
val jsonSchema = spark
  .read
  .option("multiLine", true) // <-- the trick
  .json("sample.json")
  .schema
scala> jsonSchema.printTreeString
root
 |-- entity: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- vehicle: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- current_status: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- position: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- trip: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- route_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- schedule_relationship: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- start_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- trip_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- vehicle: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gtfs_realtime_version: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- incrementality: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user-data: string (nullable = true)
```

The trick is to use `multiLine` option so the entire file is a single row that you use to infer schema from.

Comment: That's true. It gives me an error due to library-dependencies, but it should works otherwise. I have used the StructType object and have defined manually all the fields and it works. Thanks!
This works for static files, but I'm reading the data from a  Kafka topic for a streaming application and it does not infer the schema. Do you know about it?

Answer (score -1):

use

df = spark.read.json(r's3://mypath/', primitivesAsString='true')