# How to find out the schema from a tons of messy structured data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a huge dataset with messy structured schema.
Say, the same data fields can have different data type of data, for example, `data.tags` can be a list of string or a list of object

I tried to load the JSON data from hdfs and print the schema but it occurs the error below.
`TypeError: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>`

Here is the code

```py
    data_json = sc.textFile(data_path)
    data_dataset = data_json.map(json.loads)
    data_dataset_df = data_dataset.toDF()
    data_dataset_df.printSchema()
```

Is it possible to figure out the schema something like

```
root
 |-- children: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: boolean (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |-- element: string
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- occupation: string (nullable = true)
```

in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to find how to infer the schema of a JSON file. You should take a look at reading the JSON into a DataFrame straightaway, instead of through a Python mapping function.

Also, I'm referring you to [How to infer schema of JSON files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760682/how-to-infer-schema-of-json-files), as I think it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, this method can show the schema quickly but how to figure out which data fields are wrong type or missing?

Comment: If you're - by any chance - using Databricks, try out [`badRecordsPath`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html). Otherwise, you could use `PERMISSIVE` mode:
`spark.read.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("/path/to/user.json")` If you see some columns having the wrong data type, you could filter those out by mapping values to something else.